# NZEC error in java on codechef

Tags: java, runtime-error

I get a NZEC (Non zero Exit code) error for my program on codechef, while it works perfectly on bluej:

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

According to Gregorian Calendar, it was Monday on the date 01/01/2001. If any year is input, 
Write a program to display what is the day on the 1st January of this year.
Input

The first line contains an integer T, total number of testcases. Then follow T lines, each line contains an integer year.
Output

Display the day on the 1st January of that year in lowercase letter.
Constraints

1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
1900≤ A,B,C ≤2500

MY SOULTION:

```
import java.io.*;
class ex15 {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));           
        int t=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        for(int y=0;y<t;y++) {
            int d=0;
            int a=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
            if((2001-a)<0) {
                for(int x=2001;x<a;x++) {
                    if(x%4==0) {
                        d=d+366;
                    } else {
                        d=d+365;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for(int x=a;x<2001;x++) {
                    if(x%4==0) {
                        d=d+366;
                    } else {
                        d=d+365;
                    }
                }
            }
            String f[] = {"monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"};
            if((a-2001)<0) {
                System.out.println(f[7-(d%7)]);
            } else {
                System.out.println(f[d%7]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also what exactly is an NZEC error? and how should I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I wrote my first program on codechef.
When you submit your solution on codechef, keep your answer in a try-catch block, or else it will show NZEC error.
For example -

```
public class Main  {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         try {
                 //your complete working Code
              }
          catch(Exception e)
              {
                   return;
              }
      }
}
```